# JMS MessageListener started from ServletContextListener Stops after sometime

Tags: web-applications, jboss, richfaces, jms

I am creating a RichFaces Web Application which is running on JBOSS 5.1.0ga AS/Sun OS. The application also processes JMS Requests(Reading the Request from a Weblogic Queue running in different server and Writing the response back to the another Weblogic Queue running in that server). I used Asynchronous message processing by extending MessageListener class and started the listening in ServletContextListener. Everything works fine but after some time(atleast after 5 to 6 hours) the Listener stopped listening the queue and if i restart the server, the listener reading the old messages also. 
I am unable to understand why it is getting stopped in the middle. Is there any other efficient way to start a Listener in a Web Application?

**ServletContextListener**

```
public class WebApplicationListener implements ServletContextListener {
public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent contextEvent) {
    System.out.println("Starting the JMS Listener");
    new JMSConnector().startListening();
}

public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent contextEvent) {
}
```

}

**JMS Connector**

```
public class JMSConnector{
static Properties properties = new Properties();

static Context context;
static QueueConnectionFactory connFactory;
static {
    Properties props = new Properties();
    InputStream inputStream = new JMSConnector().getClass()
            .getClassLoader()
            .getResourceAsStream("jmsconnection.properties");
    // ClassLoader.getSystemResource("/HibernateConfigFile.properties").openStream()
    try {
        properties.load(inputStream);
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    props.setProperty(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,
            properties.getProperty("context_factory_class"));
    // props.setProperty("java.naming.factory.url.pkgs",
    // properties.getProperty("naming_url_pkgs"));
    props.setProperty(Context.PROVIDER_URL,
            properties.getProperty("provider_url"));
    try {
        context = new InitialContext(props);
        connFactory = (QueueConnectionFactory) context.lookup(properties
                .getProperty("connection_factory_name"));
    } catch (NamingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}


public void sendMessage(String responseMessage) throws Exception {

    QueueConnection conn = connFactory.createQueueConnection();
    // This session is not transacted, and it uses automatic message
    // acknowledgement
    QueueSession session = conn.createQueueSession(false,
            Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
    Queue q = (Queue) context.lookup(properties
            .getProperty("responsequeue"));
    // Sender
    QueueSender sender = session.createSender(q);
    // Text message
    TextMessage msg = session.createTextMessage();
    msg.setText(responseMessage);
    System.out.println("Sending the message: " + msg.getText());
    sender.send(msg);
    session.close();
    conn.close();
}
public void startListening() {
    try {

        System.out.println("In Start Listening");

        QueueConnection conn = connFactory.createQueueConnection();
        // This session is not transacted, and it uses automatic message
        // acknowledgement
        QueueSession session = conn.createQueueSession(false,
                Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
        Queue q = (Queue) context.lookup(properties
                .getProperty("requestqueue"));

        QueueReceiver receiver = session.createReceiver(q);
        RequestListener requestListener = new RequestListener();
        receiver.setMessageListener(requestListener);
        conn.start();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

**MessageListener**

```
public class RequestListener implements MessageListener {

/**
 * Casts the message to a TextMessage and displays its text.
 * 
 * @param message
 *            the incoming message
 */
public void onMessage(Message message) {
    System.out.println("Message Received");
    TextMessage msg = null;

    try {
        if (message instanceof TextMessage) {
            msg = (TextMessage) message;
            String requestXml = msg.getText();
            //Calling Processing Methods
            new JMSConnector().sendMessage(responseXml);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Message of wrong type: "
                    + message.getClass().getName());
        }
    } catch (JMSException e) {
        System.out.println("JMSException in onMessage(): " + e.toString());
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        System.out.println("Exception in onMessage():" + t.getMessage());
    }
}
```

}

Comment: I don't have an answer to your question but a comment on the code.  For sanity's sake, PLEASE when you catch a JMS Exception print the linked exception! The JMS exception is rather generic and the linked exception exists for the transport vendor to provide low-level detail of the transport's view of the problem. If a linked exception exists it is going to be critical in diagnosing the problem. I usually tell my clients that failure to print linked exceptions should be cause to prevent deployment to production. OK, rant complete. Hopefully someone will respond with an actual answer now.

Comment: Thanks Rob for your comment, Will try to print the Linked Exception hereafter

Comment: Why aren't you using a MDB? Your solution sounds like an unnecessary hack to me...

Comment: There is no reference to any of the items in the `startListening` method and so perhaps they are candidates for garbage collection? `connFactory` and `context` are the only member variables, perhaps this is the reason? Did you ever solve this?

Comment: You could maybe try to make `JMSConnector` a singleton and see if that works any better.